# How to escape user-supplied parameters with a SQL query?

Tags: java, security, jdbc, sql-injection

Trying to get started with JDBC (using Jetty + MySQL). I'm not sure how to escape user-supplied parameters in a SQL statement. Example:

```
String username = getDangerousValueFromUser();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("some statement where username = '" + username + "'"));
```

How do we escape "username" before use with a statement?

Answer (score 16):

Use [Prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

for example :

```
con.prepareStatement("update Orders set pname = ? where Prod_Id = ?");
pstmt.setInt(2, 100);
pstmt.setString(1, "Bob");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

It will prevent raw SQL injection

If you want to escape sql string then check for [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)). Note that that this method was [deprecated in Commons Lang 3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html).

**Also See**

- [does-using-preparedstatement-mean-there-will-not-be-any-sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750607/does-using-preparedstatement-mean-there-will-not-be-any-sql-injection)

Comment: @lvella to escape sql you can use [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29), read its doc before you use

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well, at that time I indeed needed to know how to escape parameters for an SQL query, and felt frustrated by this answer that it had nothing to do with what I needed (although it was the same thing OP asked). So don't go assuming what does or does not services someone, because it is easy to forget that not everybody does the same kind of programming tasks you are used to.

Comment: @Ivella: first off: I *honestly* can't imagine a good reason to manually escape data for an SQL statement, could you tell me what it was for you? Second: those cases are rare. Really, really rare. 90% of the time when someone asks for "escaping SQL data in Java" they simply don't know about prepared statement and assume the build-the-sql-string approach is the only one that works.

Comment: @JoachimSauer A use case: you need to generate values that go in a `IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`, where you have say in the order of 5 to 10 values. I agree about your 90% figure (it might even be higher than this). But that leaves 10% of the cases where a `PreparedStatement` doesn't cut it.

Comment: @avernet: you can do that (and I've done it): generate `IN (?, ?, ?)` and call the appropriate `set*()` methods.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That is a very good point! And now I got some code to change. So I think that 90% figure needs to be revised upwards ;).

Comment: Looking for the same answer - my usecase is calling `BULK INSERT` in SQL Server. This statement **does not accept parameter** for the bulk file name. So that is perfectly valid use case for SQL parameter escaping. But I agree that 99.99% people don't know what they are asking :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure

Comment: Another use case: constructing long WHERE clasues from SQL fragments.